# Maven Oracle 10.2.0.5.0 driver issue

Tags: maven, oracle10g

I am trying the following command to use oracle from my application but it is failing on windows 7.

> mvn install:install-file -Dfile=Z:\oracle\ojdbc14.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc14 -Dversion=10.2.0.5.0 -Dpackaging=jar

**stacktrace:**

```
 [INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven
-install-plugin/2.4/maven-install-plugin-2.4.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-install-plugin:2.4: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 o
r one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descrip
tor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.4
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven
-deploy-plugin/2.7/maven-deploy-plugin-2.7.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-deploy-plugin:2.7: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7 or
one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descripto
r for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:2.7
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven
-site-plugin/3.3/maven-site-plugin-3.3.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-site-plugin:3.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3 or one
of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor fo
r org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:jar:3.3
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven
-antrun-plugin/1.3/maven-antrun-plugin-1.3.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-antrun-plugin:1.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3 or
one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descripto
r for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:jar:1.3
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven
-assembly-plugin/2.2-beta-5/maven-assembly-plugin-2.2-beta-5.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plu
gin:2.2-beta-5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read
artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:2.2-b
eta-5
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven
-dependency-plugin/2.8/maven-dependency-plugin-2.8.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-dependency-plugin:2.8: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin
:2.8 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact d
escriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.8
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.473 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-05-20T10:27:58-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 or one of its d
ependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.ap
ache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.4: Failure to transfer org.apache.
maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:pom:2.4 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/ma
ven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted unti
l the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original err
or: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:po
m:2.4 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.
org -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugi
ns:maven-install-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Fa
iled to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plug
in:jar:2.4
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.re
solve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginD
escriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:179)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDes
criptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:284)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(D
efaultBuildPluginManager.java:241)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.getMojoDesc
riptor(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:238)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalcul
ator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:103)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalcul
ator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:83)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lifecycl
eStarter.java:89)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
cher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
uncher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
356)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to
read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2
.4
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.
loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:282)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.
readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:198)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.readArtifact
Descriptor(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:287)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.re
solve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:103)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to
 transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:pom:2.4 from https://rep
o.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will no
t be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are
 forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:ma
ven-install-plugin:pom:2.4 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
): repo.maven.apache.org
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(Defa
ultArtifactResolver.java:444)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtif
acts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtif
act(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.
loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:267)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Failure to tra
nsfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:pom:2.4 from https://repo.ma
ven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be
 reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are for
ced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-
install-plugin:pom:2.4 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): r
epo.maven.apache.org
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newExcepti
on(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:238)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtif
act(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:183)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownlo
ads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:585)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownl
oads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:503)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(Defa
ultArtifactResolver.java:421)
        ... 27 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResoluti
onException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to proxy. Proxy setting were changed.

Answer (score 0):

try deleting the failed artifact from your `local maven repository` and try again. In your case, delete this directory and try again.

> C:/Users//.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin

Comment: I tried that but seeing this inside plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.4 folder:#NOTE: This is an Aether internal implementation file, its format can be changed without prior notice.
#Fri May 20 13:27:34 CDT 2016
@default-central-https\://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.lastUpdated=1463768854961
https\://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.error=Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins\:maven-

install-plugin\:pom\:2.4 from/to central (https\://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)\: repo.maven.apache.org

Comment: If you delete the files, new files will be downloaded again. Its because of some of the files in that directory were corrupted/outdated. Error contains the artifacts are `cached in the local repository`. To be safer, rename/move the directory.

Comment: Yes. I deleted the directory and run the command again... but getting same error.